# Error authenticating with SSL Web service

Tags: vb.net, ssl, service, web

I'm getting the following error when I try to call a web service method that uses SSL authentication, the certificate has been already installed on the machine and I can successfully open the web service in Google Chrome. I've been stuck for the past two days and I don't know what else to do.

```
Function Deceval(ByVal xmlstr As String, ByVal certname As String, ByRef error_cert As Boolean, ByRef user As String, ByRef password As String, ByRef vectrama As String(), ByRef url As String, ByVal vecrutas As String(), ByVal cert As X509Certificate2)
    Try
        Dim WSCompany As SDLService = New SDLService()
        Dim petitionWS As RequestCreateReceiptServiceDTO = New RequestCreateReceiptServiceDTO()
        Dim answerFromWS As ResponseReceiptServiceDTO
        Dim signatureToken As X509SecurityToken = New X509SecurityToken(cert)
        Dim userNameToke As New UsernameToken(user, password)
        Dim x509str As X509SecurityToken = New X509SecurityToken(signatureToken.Certificate)
        Dim sig As New MessageSignature(x509str)
        
        WSCompany.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(userNameToke)
        WSCompany.RequestSoapContext.Security.Elements.Add(sig)
        WSCompany.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(x509str)
        WSCompany.RequestSoapContext.Security.Timestamp.TtlInSeconds = 60


        Dim soapHeader As HeaderDTO = New HeaderDTO()
        petitionWS.Header = soapHeader
        'This date was hardcoded because I thought the error was caused
        'by a time zone difference (it is not apparently)
        petitionWS.Header.Date = "2012-12-20T17:21:30Z"
        petitionWS.Header.Hour = "17:21PM"
        petitionWS.Header.User = "oraclell"
        petitionWS.Header.DepositCode = "110011"

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(obj As [Object], certificate As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain, errors As SslPolicyErrors)
                                                                      Return True
                                                                  End Function

        WSCompany.ClientCertificates.Add(signatureToken.Certificate)
        WSCompany.Url = serviceURL
        'Calling the createReceipt() web service method. The error shows up when stepping in the line below :(
        answerFromWS = WSCompany.createReceipt(petitionWS)

        Return ""
    Catch ex As Exception
        error_cert = True
        register.log("Error consuming web service -- " & ex.ToString, "Log_ConsWS.txt", webFilePaths)
        Return xmlstr
    End Try
End Function
```

This causes the following error:

```
Security token failed to validate. weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.SecurityTokenValidateResult@4c104c10[status: false][msg [
```

Below is the link with the stack trace:

[Stack trace - Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/aHcTRKiu)

Any help or clue will be greatly appreciated.